# What is the setter doing in this code? ES6: Use getters and setters to Control Access to an Object

Tags: javascript

I understand that the reason for this code is to change fahrenheit to celsius but what is the setter doing in the code if the get is already returning the temp in celsius?

```
function makeClass() {
  "use strict";
  /* Alter code below this line */
  class Thermostat{
    constructor(value){
      this._fahrenheit = value;
    }
    get temperature(){
      return (5/9 * (this._fahrenheit - 32));
    }
    set temperature(value){
      this._fahrenheit - (value * 9) / 5.0 + 32;
    }
  }
  /* Alter code above this line */
  return Thermostat;
}
const Thermostat = makeClass();
const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // setting in Farenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in C
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in C
```

Comment: Calling the one `.temperature` and the other `.fahrenheit` doesn't make sense. If at all, you should have a `Temperature` class with `.fahrenheit`, `.celsius` and `.kelvin` properties.

Comment: The setter makes no sense. Surely that should have been a `=` assignment not a `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By implementing the setter function you allow the user to still get the correct value either they choose to know the temperature in Celsius or Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the setter does not appear to be useful at all. In fact it prevents the class from working as (supposedly) intended.

This line has no effect as it does not update the `_fahrenheit` property:

```
this._fahrenheit - (value * 9) / 5.0 + 32;
```

It should just "record" the new value and let the getter make the conversion:

```js
function makeClass() {
  "use strict";

  class Thermostat {
    constructor(value) {
      this._fahrenheit = value;
    }
    get temperature() {
      return (5 / 9 * (this._fahrenheit - 32));
    }
    set temperature(value) {
      this._fahrenheit = value;
    }
  }
  return Thermostat;
}
const Thermostat = makeClass();
const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // setting in Farenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.4444° Celcius
console.log(thermos.temperature);
thermos.temperature = 98.6;
console.log(thermos.temperature); // 37° Celcius
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. Surely `temp.temperature = temp.temperature` should not change anything.

Comment: I agree, there should simply be a method to convert to Celcius.

Answer (score 1):

It make some calculations but do not return any values nor sets any variables. Other than consume minimal processor time it doesn't do anything.